# Question on Trigeometry

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing this question and I found out why a, b, and c can't be the answer.
What about d, and e? I don't understand them.
P.S the right answer is d :)
Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: There is not even an angle whose sine is $\pi$, since $\pi$ is too big.

Answer (score 3):

$\sin^{-1}(\pi)$ in words means the angle whose sine is $\pi$. If $\frac{opposite}{hypotenuse} = \pi$, then the angle whose sides have that ratio would most certainly not be zero.

$\cos^{-1}(1)$ in words means the angle whose cosine is $1$. This is always going to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, like @okarin says, $\sin^{-1}(\pi)$ is the angle whose sine is $\pi$. Think about what you know about $\sin(x)$ though. What is the minimum value $\sin(x)$ can be? What is the maximum value $\sin(x)$ can be? (Hover over the box below for the answers.)

> The minimum value of $\sin(x)$ is $-1$. The maximum value of $\sin(x)$ is $1$.

Now, we know that $\pi \approx 3.14\ldots$. Using this and the maximum value of $\sin(x)$, what can you say?

> We know that there does not exist an angle whose sine is $\pi$ since $\pi>1$ and $1$ is the maximum value $\sin(x)$ can be.